# Facebook extenbded permission in tab application

Tags: facebook

How can I do this.. The following fan page tab application has this functionality.

http://www.facebook.com/iebschool?v=app_140944359256268

click on the fourth tab and it will ask for extended permission.. am not sure how to do this.. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fbml tag for that:

[`fb:prompt-permission`](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:prompt-permission)

**Example:**

```
<fb:prompt-permission perms="email">
  Would you like to receive email from our application?
</fb:prompt-permission>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a more robust function with FBJS that allows you to have a callback function when the permissions are complete.

```
Facebook.showPermissionDialog('offline_access', postComment);
```

postComment would be my callback function on success.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the FBML and FBJS answers already given, you might find the following two links useful — [Authentication for Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and [Apps on Facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/)

Whilst existing FBML apps are unaffected for now, FBML has been formally deprecated by Facebook and new FBML applications cannot now be created, so it's worth learning how to do it on the server side for iframe applications, before you need to build one in a hurry  ;o)